# Java Default NumberFormat Currency symbol

Tags: java

I'm using NumberFormat's format() method to format currency in my application. When obtaining the currency instance, I'm not passing any locale to the method. 
I've deployed this code to my app cluster which contains two nodes/servers. Interestingly, on one of the app server, the formattedAmmt is $xxxx.xx but on the other one it is ¤xxxx.xx. As far as I understand, this character is a universal currency symbol and JDK uses this when no particular locale is available. Is my understanding correct? If yes, how come it is working on one of the app server but not on the other? We are not seeing any default locale or such properties in app server/JVM properties.

```
double amount = xxxx.xx;
String formattedAmt = NumberFormat.getCurrencyInstance().format(amount);
```

PS: I'm deploying this app to WebSphere app server cluster which is using JDK 1.6.

Answer (score 1):

Based on the java doc : https://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/text/NumberFormat.html#getCurrencyInstance()

`public static final NumberFormat getCurrencyInstance()
Returns a currency format for the current default locale.`

It will base on the current locale of the server. That's why you may have two differents behavior.

If you want to specify the local, you have to use the following method:

`public static NumberFormat getCurrencyInstance(Locale inLocale) 
Returns a currency format for the specified locale`